# Regex Validation Not working for large Numbers in column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to validate columns over a particular regex in dataframe. The Limit of number is (20,3) i.e maximum 20 length with int datatype or 23 with float datatype . but pandas is converting original number to random int number and my regex validation is getting failed . I checked my regex is proper .

Dataframe :

```
FirstColumn,SecondColumn,ThirdColumn
111900987654123.123,111900987654123.123,111900987654123.123
111900987654123.12,111900987654123.12,111900987654123.12
111900987654123.1,111900987654123.1,111900987654123.1
111900987654123,111900987654123,111900987654123
111900987654123,-111900987654123,-111900987654123
-111900987654123.123,-111900987654123.123,-111900987654123.1
-111900987654123.12,-111900987654123.12,-111900987654123.12
-111900987654123.1,-111900987654123.1,-111900987654123.1
11119009876541231111,1111900987654123,1111900987654123
```

Code:

```
NumberValidationRegexnegative = r"^-?[0-9]{1,20}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$"
df_CPCodeDF=pd.read_csv("D:\\FTP\LocalUser\\NCCLCOLL\\COLLATERALUPLOAD\\upld\\SplitFiles\\AACCR6675H_22102021_07_1 - Copy.csv")
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.3f}'.format)
rslt_df2=df_CPCodeDF[df_CPCodeDF.iloc[:, 0].notna()]
rslt_df1=rslt_df2[~rslt_df2.iloc[:,0].apply(str).str.contains(NumberValidationRegexnegative, regex=True)].index   
print("rslt_df1",rslt_df1)
```

Output Result:

```
rslt_df1 Int64Index([8], dtype='int64')
```

Expected Result:

```
rslt_df1 Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Then why do you have this line "print("index ",i)" if you don't want index to be printed ?

Comment: pd.set_option here only formats the results when you print or display your dataframe to terminal/notebook. In your `rslt_df1` assignment line, try formatting inline by replacing `.apply(str)` with `.apply(lambda x: f'{x:.3f}')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `dtype=str` as parameter of `pd.read_csv`:

```
NumberValidationRegexnegative = r"^-?[0-9]{1,20}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$"
df_CPCodeDF = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype=str)

rslt_df2 = df_CPCodeDF[df_CPCodeDF.iloc[:, 0].notna()]
rslt_df1 = rslt_df2[~rslt_df2.iloc[:,0] \
               .str.contains(NumberValidationRegexnegative, regex=True)].index
```

Output:

```
>>> print("rslt_df1", rslt_df1)
rslt_df1 Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
```